# How to set a Fragment in RelativeLayout by code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I create a simple project without Layout XML.And I meet a question which I cannot add a Fragment Object to RelativeLayout Object,RelativeLayout's addview() method cannot  add Fragment.
Then I found a solution

```
Fragment fr = new FirstFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = ((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        ll.setId(12300011);
        ft.add(ll.getId(), fr).commit();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(dm.widthPixels/2,dm.heightPixels/2);//dm is a DisplayMetrics Object
        rl.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        instance.addView(ll, rl);//instance is a RelativeLayout Object
```

But it not a good solution I think,because I must make a ViewGroup(LinearLayout).

I want to add Fragment in a RelativeLayout by code,does somebody know the better solution? 
Apologize for my English,Thanks for help.

Comment: I have finding something...
FragmentTransaction's "replace(x)" method is a replace method that instead a view to "x",so I can set a view in relativeLayout with  site or rules,then call the replace() method to set my Fragment.
Maybe "How to use FragmentTransaction's add() method to set a Fragment in a RelativeLayout with rules" is a better question about my confuse.